# DES- If LSB is removed, are the key B and C the same?

Tags: encryption, des

I believe that in DES every 8th bit is ignored of the key. That means B and C are same if the LSB is ignored. So, shouldn't encrypting a message by the key all Bs be able to be decrypted by key with all Cs? I tried doing it but did not work. I used this tool to check : http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/descalc/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASCII letters `B` and `C` are represented by the bytes 0x42 and 0x43, which indeed are equivalent in a DES key since they differ by the low-order bit only. However the tool used accepts keys in hexadecimal, and the byte 0xBB and 0xCC are not equivalent key bytes for DES.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I totally missed the Hex part. In my head I was like B and C are ASCII B and C. Did not think straight. My bad. THank you so much!